# unity3d - System.DllNotFoundException: MonoPosixHelper when calling REST API with Content Encoding gzip

Tags: rest, unity-game-engine, encoding, gzip, restsharp

calling a REST API with Response Header Content Encoding gzip with RestSharp causes problems. If I exec the code as a simple ConsoleApplication with Visual Studio, there is no problem, so only Unity cannot handle this. Anyone with an idea?

```
     var client = new RestClient("http://rest.sandbox-immobilienscout24.de");
     var request = new RestRequest("/restapi/api/search/v1.0/search/region", Method.GET);
     client.ClearHandlers();
     request.AddQueryParameter("realestatetype", realestatetype);
     request.AddQueryParameter("geocodes", geocodes);
     request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
     request.AddHeader("Systemauthorization", "blabla");
     IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
     Debug.Log("search:" +response.ErrorException);
```

Response Headers:

```
 Cache-Control →private
 Content-Encoding →gzip
 Content-Type →application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Date →Sun, 06 Nov 2016 14:21:03 GMT
 Expires →Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
 L-IS24-ApiClient →blaKey
 L-IS24-RequestRefnum →06be3d11-6526-4664-acd1-0787dbd7d1f6
 Server →Apache
 Transfer-Encoding →chunked
 Vary →Accept-Encoding
```

Exception:

```
search:System.Net.WebException: MonoPosixHelper ---> System.DllNotFoundException: MonoPosixHelper
   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream:CreateZStream (System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode,bool,System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream/UnmanagedReadOrWrite,intptr)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream..ctor (System.IO.Stream compressedStream, CompressionMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Boolean gzip) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream:.ctor (System.IO.Stream,System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode,bool,bool)
   at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream..ctor (System.IO.Stream compressedStream, CompressionMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
   at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream..ctor (System.IO.Stream compressedStream, CompressionMode mode) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.Compression.GZipStream:.ctor (System.IO.Stream,System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode)
   at System.Net.HttpWebResponse..ctor (System.Uri uri, System.String method, System.Net.WebConnectionData data, System.Net.CookieContainer container) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.HttpWebResponse:.ctor (System.Uri,string,System.Net.WebConnectionData,System.Net.CookieContainer)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
   at RestSharp.Http.GetRawResponse (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
 UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
 ApiClient:callSearchApi(String, String) (at Assets/ApiClient.cs:33)
 ApiClient:Start() (at Assets/ApiClient.cs:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

After Unity 2.6.1 this functional not used there, try using WWW or WWWForm

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html

Comment: Thank you, but how in detail can I do that? What do I have to do in Unity?

Comment: I change my answer, check links

Comment: That means I cannot use RestSharp?

Comment: Unfortunately, have to use the built-in tools

Comment: I cannot see anything about Query Parameters, Headers or Authentication in that library... is that true?

Comment: Yes, but you use the default C# functions

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/en-en/library/system.net.httpwebresponse(v=vs.110).aspx use this

Comment: Is there an example where `HttpWebResponse` and `WWW` is used?

Comment: Examples are according to the links

Comment: But there is only WWW used. Do you know examples where I can use HttpWebResposne for example headers and WWW for encoding?

Comment: No no, HttpWebResponse alternative WWW, not supported

Comment: HttpWebResponse is the alternative which works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have several option to interact with web. including

1. [**WWW**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html)

> The WWW class can be used to send both GET and POST requests to the
>   server. The WWW class will use GET by default and POST if you supply a
>   postData parameter.

2. [**UnityWebRequest**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html)

> The UnityWebRequest is a replacement for Unity’s original WWW object.
>   It provides a modular system for composing HTTP requests and handling
>   HTTP responses. The primary goal of the UnityWebRequest system is to
>   permit Unity games to interact with modern Web backends. It also
>   supports high-demand features such as chunked HTTP requests, streaming
>   POST/PUT operations and full control over HTTP headers and verbs.

Comment: Neither of these solutions supports Rest APIs like Restsharp does.

Comment: so answer the question using restSharp. https://github.com/Cratesmith/RestSharp-for-unity3d